# Interrupting Python scripts and Jupyter Notebook on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am running a python script on VS code (*.py). Simultaneously, I am running a cell on Jupyter Notebook on VS Code. If I interrupt the kernel of the jupyter cell, will this interrupt the procedure on the py script?

Comment: maybe simply try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are independent.

The kernel in ipynb does not affect the terminals used by Python